# FTP acknowledgement mule esb

Tags: file, ftp, mule

I have a scenario like a huge zip file comes and i need to post it some FTP server.

**Requirement**

I need an acknowledgment after file gets copied to the destination FTP. does Mule FTP outbound enpoint or FTP connector provide an acknowledgment option.

Please let me know what possible options are there.

Do comment incase of any clarification required.

Answer (score 0):

Mule does not have an acknowledgement capability when a file get copied in FTP, but you could do something like this.

```
 <ftp:connector name="FTP" pollingFrequency="1000" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="FTP"/>
<flow name="exampleFlow">
    <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" connector-ref="FTP"/>

  <!-- Add an email or jms message component -->
</flow>
```

After the ftp copying is done, the next processor of ftp(processor) is executed.
Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Mule FTP component does not have the acknowledgement capability when file copied in ftp. If you are looking for a ack capability then you can use the JMS/AMQ.